# postgres EXPLAIN ANALYSE results VS DataGrip results

Tags: sql, postgresql, explain, datagrip

I see 2 duration results for the same query in `Datagrip` and with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`:

[image]

DataGrip: 66ms
EXPLAIN ANALYSE: 0.056

What is the difference between them? Are they both specify milliseconds?

Comment: The units are both "ms" so both are milliseconds.  The first is the time to compile the query.  The second is the time to run it.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" and "second"? There are 4 durations in the screenshot

Comment: The difference is probably network latency or slow processing on the client side.

Comment: The 66ms reported by DataGrip is the time it took DataGrip to receive the execution plan and display it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so DataGrip.executionPlan is including the DataGrip.fetching? so display+execution = 66-23=43ms? it doesn't make sense according to EXPLAIN ANALYSE... What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you are missing the 89ms DataGrip is reporting. I would interpreted this as: 1.DataGrip prepares the query and sends it to the database, when waits for database. 2. The database parses the query and executes it (total 0.171ms -> planning + execution from explain plan) 3. then transmits to DataGrip. All on this DataGrip records as 66ms, 4. Finally  DataGrip takes 23ms fetching (and formatting) the data returned.  Time in database 0.171ms, total time 89ms) That's display+execution = 66+23=89ms. EXPLAIN ANALYSE does not know about anything except planning + execution of the query.

Comment: None of this makes sense.  I can create a query that EXPLAIN ANALYSE claims takes 10ms and returns one single row, but datagrip takes 5 seconds to display.  This isn't due to network latency, it's just because postgres doesn't give accurate timings.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between them?

`EXPLAIN ANALYSE` shows a query execution that server gives you.

`DataGrip` shows actual execution time with network latency, network round trip, display and query time itself.

> Are they both specify milliseconds?

Yes, in `ms`, as it mentioned in the screenshot

Comment: Right, but this doesn't held true in my experience. I routinely see values that just do not sum.  And not even slightly off, seconds off!

Comment: Could you file an issue for that in [DataGrip bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE)?

Comment: I don't think I could really call it a Datagrip issue. The problem is that Postgres is just slow to actually transfer the data.  I suppose you could call it 'network round trip', but it's because postgres will start sending a stream of bytes really slowly.  I think this is due to some internal choices the postgres team made.